# Duplicated button doesnt change its text

Tags: jquery, html, css, jscript

i am implementing a tic tac toe game but with special specification that when i press a button it open a new DIV of the game and disable the old one and the button pressed must be changed in both DIV and so on but when i click button it change the original div not the one i want it to be updated so any help ?
Thanks in adance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .xo {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px;
        background-color: #F03;
        height: 300px;
        width: 310px;
        text-transform: capitalize;

    }
    .btn {
        background-color: #0C9;
        height: 100px;
        width: 100px;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    var c = new Number(); 
    c=0;
    i=0;
    var toPlay = 0;

    var name = "xo"+c;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(document).on('click','.btn',function(){
            alert(name);
            var id = event.target.id;
            if(c%2===0){
            $("#"+id).attr("value","X");
            $("#"+id).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
            else if(c%2!==0){
                $("#"+id).attr("value","O");
            $("#"+id).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }


            newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            newDiv.className="xo";
            var $copy =$("#"+name).html();
            document.getElementById(name).appendChild(newDiv);
                    var allChildNodes = document.getElementById(name).getElementsByTagName('*');
    for(var i = 0; i < allChildNodes.length; i++)
    {
       allChildNodes[i].disabled = true;
    }   
            c++;
            name = "xo"+c;
            alert(name);
            newDiv.id=name; 
            toPlay++;
            $("#"+name).html($copy);


        });

    });

    </script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="xo" id="xo0">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" name="1" id="1" value="Submit" />
        <input type="submit" class="btn" name="2" id="2" value="Submit" />
        <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn" id="3" value="Submit" />

        <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn" id="4" value="Submit" />
        <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn" id="5" value="Submit" />
        <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn" id="6" value="Submit" />

        <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn" id="7" value="Submit" />
        <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn" id="8" value="Submit" />
        <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn" id="9" value="Submit" />

    <br></br>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please put this in JS fiddle and show the output??

Comment: You're using `event` to get target as there is no such a variable you're passing to an event!

Comment: What's the purpose of this 'special specification'?

Comment: **Duplicate IDs** ????

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/KXp4D/120/ wat u want from this tell ??? tell me now???

Comment: i want to change the new button text also like the first div upwards also make the click button in the new div disabled when clicked on it  the code work good for the original div but i dont know what is the problem when it go to the duplicated divs :D
@Praveen.J

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is duplicate IDs. ID's **must** be unique use classes instead.

**jQuery**

```
    var id = this.id;
    if (c % 2 === 0) {
        $("." + id).val("X");
        $("." + id).prop("disabled", true);
    } else if (c % 2 !== 0) {
        $("." + id).val("O");
        $("." + id).prop("disabled", true);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
    <input type="submit" class="btn 1" name="1" id="1" value="Submit" />
    <input type="submit" class="btn 2" name="2" id="2" value="Submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn 3" id="3" value="Submit" />

    <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn 4" id="4" value="Submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn 5" id="5" value="Submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn 6" id="6" value="Submit" />

    <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn 7" id="7" value="Submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn 8" id="8" value="Submit" />
    <input type="submit" name="3" class="btn 9" id="9" value="Submit" />
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KXp4D/123/)